# How do I configure a Django model against an agreggating postgres view?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Django 4.2.9, postgres 15.2 (server), Python 3.10

I have a view that does it's own aggregation and I want to map it into a Django Model.

```
CREATE VIEW report_usage AS
SELECT t.team_id, t.display_name, t.report_allowance, count(r.*) as "monthly_usage"
FROM report r
LEFT JOIN teams t ON t.team_id = r.team_id
WHERE date_trunc('month', r.response_ts) = date_trunc('month', now())
GROUP BY t.team_id, t.display_name, report_allowance;
```

This view works as promised; it counts the number of reports run by each team. Now that view is also used in other places so I want to simply incorporate it into a Django model for use in my app.

So I built a Django Model around it:

```
class ReportUsage(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        verbose_name_plural = 'Report Usage'
        db_table = 'report_usage'

    # Not really a key for this table.. just needed by django
    team_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='team_id')
    display_name = models.CharField(db_column='display_name')
    report_allowance = models.IntegerField(db_column='report_allowance')
    report_usage = models.IntegerField(db_column='count')
```

## However

It is not working:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "report_usage.team_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> LINE 1: SELECT "report_usage"."team_id", "report_usage"."display_n...

Which makes a total of zero sense to me.  At a guess, Django saw the count() function and decided to take over.

I have read everything I could find here, but this case appears to be unique because I need Django to treat the view like a table and just map fields (I will handle the read onlyness later).

I suspect that Django is not going to help me here and I can easily fake a model object on my own with the results of a query, but if there is a trick I am missing, I'd appreciate hearing about it.

## UPDATE

Ok..  it turns out that this was all just one stupid mistake.

In the model above, I look for the column 'count' (should have been a clue there.. that's a bad name for a column).

In the view the column is defined as 'monthly_usage' which is a much better name.  Changing the model to reference the proper column named fixed everything.

It is worth noting that the error was absolutely, even remarkably, useless.  As always, my value is as an example of what not to do.

Comment: I should note that I have tried all kinds of things here.  I made a synthetic id row with  `SELECT row_number() OVER () as id,` for example. 

Also I recognize that I am grouping on unique fields (team_id) but that shouldn't matter.   And yes, in real life the views should be called 'this_month' or something :-)